# how to know which function is associated with which package in rstats

Tags: r

Rookie here,

Usually, R-scripts are like follows:

```
library(packageA)
library(packageB)

functionX(code)
functionY(code)
```

So, how to know which function is associated with which package?

Why do not code packageA.functionY like other languages?

Comment: You can. If you want, use `packageA::functionX()`. Generally the way R was used at first and how many people use R today it is not needed. As you use it, you start to get a hang of what is where, but I can see how for somebody new it might be confusing to get a script that loads a few libraries and have to figure out where things came from.

Comment: thanks for responses. My point: Imagine a script with many packages and the double of functions in use. Its seems chaotic for a novice to know who comes from who, right?

Answer (score 1):

Typically speaking we don't specify the package before a function because it's not needed and it's less writing. That does not mean that it's not possible however. You can use the notation `package_name::function_name()` to load functions from packages without even the need to `library()` them. This is mostly used when loaded packages have overlapping function names.

To get a list of all functions used in a certain code the package `NCmisc` has a very handy function:

```
NCmisc::list.functions.in.file("app.R")

$.GlobalEnv
[1] "dt.data"

$`c("package:lubridate", "package:data.table")`
[1] "isoweek" "month"   "year"   

$`character(0)`
 [1] "."             "dt.Cycle"      "dt.filter"     "dt.KPI"        "dt.monthly"    "dt.MQQ"        "dt.overunder"  "dt.shops"      "dt.sorterrfid" "dt.WO"         "dt.YTD"       

$`package:base`
 [1] "as.Date"  "c"        "library"  "list"     "max"      "order"    "paste"    "paste0"   "readRDS"  "round"    "sum"      "Sys.Date"

$`package:billboarder`
[1] "bb_legend"         "bb_linechart"      "bb_x_axis"         "bb_y_axis"         "bb_y_grid"         "bbaes"             "billboarder"       "billboarderOutput" "renderBillboarder"

$`package:data.table`
[1] "melt.data.table" "setcolorder"    

$`package:shiny`
 [1] "br"                 "checkboxGroupInput" "conditionalPanel"   "dataTableOutput"    "div"                "downloadButton"     "downloadHandler"    "numericInput"       "radioButtons"      
[10] "reactive"           "renderDataTable"    "selectInput"        "shinyApp"           "tabPanel"           "tabsetPanel"       

$`package:shinydashboard`
[1] "dashboardBody"    "dashboardHeader"  "dashboardPage"    "dashboardSidebar"

$`package:utils`
[1] "write.csv"
```

When using this function just make sure that you have the packages loaded. It can only check the function names in packages that are in your loaded library.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here with two different answers.

> Why do not code packageA.functionY like other languages?

As others have commented, this is indeed possible in R with `package_name::function_name()`. Doing so does not require the package to be loaded/attached (with, say, `library(package_name)`). With `::`, you also have the advantage of using the function you *intended* to use -- instead of inadvertently calling a function by the same name from another package. And, as you say, it can improve readability. Keep in mind there's a tiny penalty in runtime by using `::`.

> So, how to know which function is associated with which package?

The approach is to find the *environment* containing the function, from which you can identify the package. You can do this using the `get_env()` function from the **rlang** package. For example, the `sd()` function comes from the **stats** package:

```r
rlang::get_env(sd)
#> <environment: namespace:stats>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Unfortunately, `get_env()` does not work for all R objects, such as data frames. The superseded package **pryr** has a function, `where()`, that is more flexible. For example, we can see that `mtcars` comes from the **datasets** package:

```r
pryr::where("mtcars")
#> <environment: package:datasets>
#> attr(,"name")
#> [1] "package:datasets"
#> attr(,"path")
#> [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/datasets"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>